# Remove passers-by from picture, by taking the same picture several times

Tags: gratis, android, linux, image-processing, photography

I want to take a picture of a building, but there are always a few people walking in front of it. While I wait for a person to exit the frame, another person comes in from the other side.

So, I thought I would take several pictures (same position, same settings, same lighting) and combine them to get a perfect picture with only the building and no pesky humans.

What software could allow me to do this easily?

- Gratis
- Runs on Linux or Android
- No big quality loss
- Bonus if it can reposition the input images that do not have *exactly* the same conditions (for instance handheld camera, reflection from a passing car, lighting change depending on the clothes of the passers-by)
- If Android, being part of a (gratis) camera app is acceptable.

Comment: If you have a "real" camera, then the answer is a tripod and a long exposure. I guess there's no reason why not to do that with a smartphone. See also https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is a superb Android Camera App with that feature built-in acceptable if the app is paid? My favorite one has that as "remove unwanted objects".

Comment: Related from photo: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93136/how-do-i-achieve-the-technique-which-creates-the-illusion-of-busy-locations-bein/93137#93137

Comment: @Mawg: I believe that long exposure is not optimal in term of image quality: Passing people affect the color of the result, especially people who stop to check their smartphone or walk toward the camera. I believe software can do better, possibly even handheld.

Comment: @Izzy: Looking for gratis first :-)

Comment: @Corey: Thanks! "Median blending" sounds like it will solve my problem, now I have to find software that has this feature :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul understood! Just ping me if you want to have my solution then ;)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, no worries. There's pros and cons to long exposure vs median blending. It's a misnomer, though, that passersby always affect long exposures. I try to shoot my daytime LE's in the 15-30 minute range. A person would have to be stationary for a good bit to be even a partial ghost in the resultant image. Median blending will allow you to not have to go to such LE extremes. Good luck!

Comment: Nicolas, you might want to try it. I have taken many long exposure photographs over the decades and  have been generally satisfied (annoying, though, if you wait all that time and it doesn't pan out). If people are affecting your picture, then your exposure is not long enough, and I can't see how interpolating adjacent pixels could produce a better result. I particularly like the deep colo(u)r saturation that comes from long exposure. On reflection though, I doubt that you could stop down the aperture on a smartphone enough for a decent long exposure, so lets see if you get a software solution

Comment: @Mawg - there's probably a phone app out there that would let you get the shutter speed down to 15 minutes on your phone (most phones are fixed aperture, generally pretty open [~f/2.2]). But, I use 10 - 16 stops of ND for daylight LE's. I'm not sure how you would do *that* with a smart phone. Not only that, but the noise from that small a sensor could be epic. Median Blending is the way to go - but I'm with you, I do love my long exposure shots.

Comment: And you have the rep on https://photo.stackexchange.com/ to prove it :-) To be honest, I am looking forward to an answer on this one, just to see if it is possible

Answer (score 3):

**[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/)**

Pros:

- Gratis
- Runs on Linux
- No (big) quality loss
- Can align images

Cons:

- Some manual work involved

Howto:

Add the photos to a new project and put them all in a single image stack. You will need to add some [Blend masks](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/Blend-masks/en.shtml).

Comment: The Blend masks tutorial is very useful. The task is very time-intensive indeed, every small detail must be masked. Median blending would really help here, so I will try your other solution too.

Answer (score 1):

**GIMP / GMIC**

Pros:

- Gratis
- Runs on Linux
- Quality Improvement (!)

Cons:

- Can not align images (must be done before with e.g. [`align_image_stack`](https://wiki.panotools.org/Align_image_stack))

Howto:

1. Add the individual aligned Images as Layers.
2. Go to `Layers → Blend [median]`
3. Apply

More information [here](https://patdavid.net/2013/05/noise-removal-in-photos-with-median_6.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "Quality Improvement"?

Comment: Median Blending removes noise **and** moving objects

Comment: Could you please add the URL to align_image_stack? Also, don't list it as a cons: Simply list it as a part of the solution, and include it as the first step of your howto. Thanks! :-)

Comment: `align_image_stack` is part of hugin.

Comment: Would you mind adding what is the `align_image_stack` command line and how to open the resulting .hdr file inside Gimp? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't use `-o` but `-a` switch (and `-C`). Generally, read the man-page for more (necessary) information. Alternatively you can also use Hugin as GUI to do it and keep the aligned images..